# Python - call sample of functions from list

Tags: python, random

How to call multiple random functions from a list? I've found a way to call one random function with this:

`my_list = [f_1, f_2, f_3]`

`random.choice(my_list)()`

I tried to modify it to work with *sample* instead of *choice*, but i can't make it work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the functions all have no parameters, here's a straightforward implementation that uses `random.sample` - you can assign its returned list of sampled items to a variable, and loop through that list, and call each item:

```
num_samples = 2 # or whatever
my_list = [f_1, f_2, f_3]
sampled_functions = random.sample(my_list, num_samples)
for func in sampled_functions:
    func()
```

Your example using `random.choice` could also be written like the above, where you assign the returned value to a variable:

```
func = random.choice(my_list)
func()
```

I'm thinking your issue when using `random.sample` was that you may have tried to do something like `random.sample(my_list,num_samples)()`, which would've produced an error, because `sample` returns a list, and you can't call a list like a function.